# secure a laravel REST API with client's that act on their own behalf

Tags: laravel, rest, api, security, laravel-passport

I'm sorry if this question is asked before, but I'm still confused.

I'm currently creating a **REST API** with **laravel**. I'm using **passport** to secure the API-endpoints. The API should be used/accessed from several websites and SPA's. BUT all this sites need to access the API on there own behalf. So there is no user that need to sign in! I found a lot of tutorials that cover the topic of authorization and authentication but only on behalf of a user.

So my question is: **What oauth grant type shoud i use to secure my API considering that all api consumers act on there own behalf?**

I tried to use the `client credential grant` because the documentation said that

> The client credentials grant is suitable for machine-to-machine authentication.

But that creates a `bearer token` and it seems not save to store it in a SPA or generally on client side. 
Has someone experience in this topic and can please provide an answer (maybe with a short explanation)?

*A simple example of how I want to use some endpoints of the API to provide some context:*
I created a location endpoint that receives a zip code and returns all the relevant places. I want to use this in a form. So that the user inputs his zip code and dynamically receives all the places in a select box, so that he can choose one and proceed with the form.

Thanks in advance!